# flask-wtf form not sending form data?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

For context, I'm trying to create a flask-wtf form. I've done that and it's presented correctly:

```py
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')

@APP.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html', form=LoginForm())

@APP.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    print(request.method, request.get_json())
    return redirect('/')  # temporary
```

Here's the html:

```html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="post" enctype='application/json'>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

However, when I enter anything and click submit, what gets printed from `login()` is `POST None`. I don't understand why there's no data being sent. As an attempt to force it to be json, I added `enctype='application/json'` and nothing before or after.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't POST a form as JSON, there are only [3 options for `enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype).

In your `login()` function you can access the form through `request.form`, or when using wtforms, initialise the form in your view for hte data to be populated:

```
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()

    if login_form.validate_on_submit(): # this runs only on POST, and checks validation
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
    ...
```

Comment: You're missing an if in there if I'm not mistaken. In any case, thank you!

Comment: Good catch, fixed :)